# File header or general comment

Tags: language-agnostic, comments, header

Does anybody have a nice well structured starting comment for a file? I'm looking for something that looks nice, either fancy or very professional.

By general comment I mean the comment at the top of a file showing your name and purpose of the file.  Like this one:

```
/********************************************************           
    * hello -- program to print out "Hello World".         *   
    *                                                      *   
    * Author:  FirstName, LastName                         *   
    *                                                      *   
    * Purpose:  Demonstration of a simple program.         *   
    *                                                      *   
    * Usage:                                               *   
    *      Runs the program and the message appears.       *   
    ********************************************************/
```

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of such things.  I think that the boxes outlined in stars look like student code and only add to the visual clutter.  By all means, explain what's going on in javadocs.  Just don't clutter it so.

Comment: I guess you're right. I don't really want to add much stuff, but I would still like to add my name and some basic info

Comment: +1 duffymo; they're fiddly to maintain (which tends to mean they aren't maintained and drift out of sync with the code). Use something that's simple and makes auto-generation of API docs simple (javadocs, doxygen, etc.)

Comment: File header comments seldom get out of synch - the file's purpose doesn't usually change, and neither does the author.  It depends on what else you include in the header - usages could change, perhaps, but I wouldn't put that in the 'file header comment' but in a secondary comment near the top of the file.   Once I've created the file header, I seldom have to change it.

Comment: My experience is that file header comments very often get stale. "Author" is a useless concept for most software; what you want is "person to ask about this code" which is indeed fiddly to maintain.

Comment: When you put a comma between names, it means the last name is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) format?

```
/*! \file hello.cpp
\brief program to print out "Hello World"

Created: 2009-11-21 by FirstName, LastName \n
Modified: \n
*/
```

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this looks ugly? Why have all this markup when most people are going to read the raw source code anyway? IF you really must use a system like this, try Natural Docs.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, I prefer the following style (but these points can be applied to other languages too):

- If you would like to include some copyright stuff, do in the first one or two lines. Keep it short. If you have something more to say about this, do it in some README file or on your product's web site.
- Do not include any metainfo such as filename, last modification date, @author or @version tags. Tools like Subversion can keep track of such things much better, and duplicating this kind of information just adds unnecessary work to keep them in sync.
- Start the javadoc of your class with a sentence that summarizes its main function.
- No need to use captions like Purpose or Usage, just explain what you have to say in a few paragraphs. Forms and fields are great if a script needs to process them, but not so much if people will read them.

So to sum it up, I use something like this:

```
/* Copyright 2002-2009 Foo Ltd. All rights reserved. */

package foo.bar;

/**
 * This class does this or that.
 *
 * Now you can go into the details, try to be professional here by writing a
 * few clear, articulate paragraphs, not by drawing fancy ascii boxes.
 *
 * @see foo.bar.OtherClass
 */
public class MyClass {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For C#, [Stylecop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) enforces a header that looks like this

```
// <copyright file="filename.cs" company="Company">
// Copyright (c) 2008 All Right Reserved
// </copyright>
// <author>Mr blah blah</author>
// <email>blahblah@blahblah.com</email>
// <date>2009-11-21</date>
// <summary>File description.</summary>
```

You can configure the required company name in the copyright tag.