# How to ensure every source file has a comment header, githook or npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, githooks

Due to legal requirements in our project, every single source code file has to have few lines at the top:

```
1 //// File: filename.js
2 //// Description: Blah blah blah
3 //// Copyright: Blah Blah Blah
4 //// Changes: Blah
```

Yes this is redundant with version control information. We don't have a choice so I'd like to automate it as much as possible. If any files are missing this, then a warning should be emitted, like a linter would do.

I don't see any ESLint rules for this, but could it be added (via plugin?)

We are using create-react-app so as I understand it, adding a lint rule is only possible if we eject, which we don't want to have to do.

So, probably a better solution would be via a custom git hook, or npm pre- script. Does anything like this exist?

I have not been able to find anything Node.js specific for enforcing header comments. The only thing I could find that does this type of enforcement was [an answer about StyleCop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776731/375399) for C# with a dead link.

Comment: Are you restricted to `ESLint`, or can you install your own custom hooks? A `pre-receive` (or `update`) hook to check for that header would be trivial.

Comment: A custom hook is more desirable if I don't have to eject. So, a custom script I gather. We use TFS I don't think it supports pre-receive hooks. I think I am answering my own question. A git hook with a custom Node script and perhaps another install of a linter along side the built-in ESLint.